# How to make smart highlighting case sensitive in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

According to [the release notes for Notepad++ 6.1.7](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.1.7.html), the smart highlight feature has an option for being case sensitive.

How do I enable the case sensitive option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to *Preferences* and there (in last section) you can find it:

[image]

Simple :)

UPDATE:
Newer N++ versions now have separate section of **Preferences** window called **Highlighting**:

[image]

Comment: thanks. cant believe i missed it. i guess i scanned the labels w/o looking at the section titles.

Comment: In different versions you can find "Highlighting" in the list on the left of "Preferences".

Comment: @Bitterblue – thank you, answer updated